# Gimp Plugin: Get GImP drawable resolution

Tags: c, plugins, gimp

I m trying to get image resolution in a plugin I m writing.

But when I call resolution function the plugin crashes saying image does not exist.....

But I can access the drawble, please tell if there us any way to get resolution throuh GimpDrawable

Comment: Please, add some code to the question - the crashing code, and the error output.

Comment: If this is via http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/libgimp/libgimp-gimpimage.html#gimp-image-get-resolution, make sure that you feed it the image id, not the drawable id.